# compile dataframe information for unique column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that has multiple columns and rows. In one of the columns I have duplicates of user names and I want to generate a singular message to the user with all the other information in their respective rows - the df is sorted by user name. I have written this for loop (though I am sure I am complicating things). I am currently getting a list out of range error, that I'm sure has to do with the way I am trying to match up the users, any help would be appreciated.

```
#User  Item   Age#
user1  itemA   65
user1  itemB   70
user1  itemC   30
user2  itemAA  43
user2  itemAB  3
user3  itemBA  78
```

```
i = -1
message = 'txt'
for i, R in df.iterrows():
    i +=1
    if R['User'] != ['User'][i]:
        print ('message')
        message = R['User'] 'your item is' + str(R['Age'])
    elif R['User] == ['User'][i]:
        message2 = 'your item is' + str(R['Age'])
        message = message + message2
    else:
        print (message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get what I wanted. I created a unique list and looped through it with an imbedded loop through the dataframe to extract information for each unique user:

```
u_users = df['User'].drop_duplicates().reset_index()
u_user.columns =['i', 'unq']

for l, i in u_users.iterrows():
    message = ''
    for r, d in df.iterrows():
        if i['unq'] == d['User']:
             message = message + R['User'] ' your item is ' + str(R['Age'])
        else:
             continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with `i += 1` since in each iteration you are adding `1` to `i`, the last iteration would be out of range (you may also be skipping the first index). Also, setting `i = -1` at the beginning is unnecessary, since it will get overwritten inside the for loop as `i` becomes the indices of your dataframe.